# How to read values from xml nodes with names having increasing numer in it using php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am having an xml which contains nodes in the sequence below.

```
<text_value0>text0</text_value0>
<text_value1>text1</text_value1>
<text_value2>text2</text_value2>.............
```

Can you please suggest How can i read(parse) the value from these type of nodes without reading each and every tag,probably by using any loop or something to get all the values by code.

Comment: show your expected result

Comment: do you need in this way [text_value0] => text0 [text_value1] => text1 [text_value2] => text2 [text_value3] => text3

Comment: Hi, yes I need in that way

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
<?php 
$myXMLData ="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<note>
<text_value0>text0</text_value0>
<text_value1>text1</text_value1>
<text_value2>text2</text_value2>
<text_value3>text3</text_value3>
</note>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
foreach ($xml as $text){
  echo $text."<br>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: @user993516 is it useful for you?

Comment: Hi, the output was what i am expected but the my is large before this<text_value0>text0</text_value0).there are many tags.

Comment: @user993516 so what any how it's running in loop.so no matter if you have so many tags also

Comment: Hi See, i need parsing this tags values only at some point in the xml parsing.Like as you have used for loop it will consider previous nodes also.I need this at some particular point